# A Different way of adding AdMob?

Tags: ios, admob, ads

In the past week, i've been wanting to add ads to my game to earn some revenue, and I found this service called AdMob. When I wanted to add ads to my game, I found it difficult to follow the instructions that AdMob had given me. So I went on YouTube to find tutorials about this topic and I found this video named "AdMob! (Firebase : Swift 2 in Xcode)"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESg0qgwLmLk&spfreload=10.

I followed the instructions and the ads appears in the simulation, but im not sure if AdMob will let me earn revenue with this method. Can anyone confirm that this will let me earn revenue?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can earn on ads mob. but make sure that at development time you need to set sandbox enviroment. if you develop directly on production sometimes google may block your account.

Comment: whats a sandbox enviroment? and how do I set it up?

Comment: add the testdevice in code. for more info refer this link:  https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#enable_test_devices

Comment: When you set to sandbox environment. Test ads is showing so that you won't be banned by Google because showing real ads inside simulator or test devices.